# Dropdown losing functionally after ajax load()

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How Can I reinitialize Bootstrap dropdown?
The issue is, I'm reloading most of my page using an ajax call with `load()`

```
<div id=container>
    //Everything 
</div>
```

and on success of ajax I made it like:

```
success: function () {
    $('#container').load('/catalog/subequipe/gerencia');
},
```

Also I tried:

```
$(document).on('change', function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

and free inside `ready`

I'm just trying make the dropdowns of the nav bar work, not filling dropdowns with new content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delegated event (as in your second attempt) won't work here as you need to completely re-initialise the plugin once the `load()` is completed. Try this:

```
success: function () {
    $('#container').load('/catalog/subequipe/gerencia', function() {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
},
```

Comment: This works once for me. The response to my POST is a view that I display in a div. But after the second Ajax call $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); doesn't get called and hence my dropdown doesn't work :\